# How has instagram implemented their login screen?

Tags: android, instagram, user-experience

Few days ago, I did a fresh install of instagram on my android phone and while I was doing the login, I could not help but stop to look at the login screen background color changes. I was so impresssed by the design/experience that I just watched the colors change for about half an hour.

I am an android developer and a design enthusiast and not knowing how to implement that experience, which enchanted my creative self, is killing me. So, this question is for all the creative geniuses of SO, how to implement that in Android? I just want to know that. Thanks a ton.

**Edit** There is one possibility that it may be predesined/prerecorded gif that is just displayed in the background. But I want to know, if this is not a gif, can this effect be produced in android programatically? If yes, then how?

Comment: it's a splash screen I see no creativity on this stuff , it can be done with gif or u can simply use splash plugin

Comment: @ZeRubeus you mean that it is a predesigned gif from some animation software that is put in the background?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XwOuTjUFexE follow this and you will be able to create you own splash screen :)

Comment: @ZeRubeus I know how to create a splash screen. I am interested in something else.

Comment: I'm not sure how they do it, but if you want to start trying it yourself, then maybe look at GradientDrawable.  My guess is that you can just create one gradient drawable and constantly change the attributes to make it animate like that.

Comment: @DeeV thanks, I will look into it.

Comment: @AmitTiwari i think this is what you are looking for, it has sample code too http://stackoverflow.com/a/36727608/2506749

Comment: @Tuna thanks for the link. I guess it should work.

Comment: @AmitTiwari it's 100% working, i was looking for the same till i came across  you question and i noticed they didn't give you an appropriate answer that's why i had to share it with you. Anyway try it and see for yourself

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You make me curious about this pretty splashscreen, so that's make me do a **reverse engineering** for the apk of Instagram and i found that they doesn't use a **Gif** or even **GradientDrawable**, they created a **CustomView** that extends **View** that every time it generates a **Bitmap** with some colors then they add on this bitmap a **blur** effect and they put it as background (very complicated).

I think it's not legal to put their closed code but i invite you to have a look in its code to have an idea.

I hope that's help you,
Good luck.

Comment: Instagram uses an image which is having rainbow color and each second it translates it to left and it looks like that color is getting changed.

Comment: How do you reverse engineer apks?

Comment: @summers easiest way to do that .... http://www.decompileandroid.com/

Comment: You could have just given him this link http://stackoverflow.com/a/36727608/2506749

Comment: @Tuna: i posted this answer in January 2016 and your link is in April 2016 so i can't get the answer from the future and post it in the past, please check the dates before you put your comment

Comment: @Context oh yes, didn't notice.... maybe you can edit your answer for others to get that link