# How background changes at login in Instagram app?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-studio

I have made my app to change background color every few milliseconds. But it is not appealing to user. If you have seen Instagram's login screen, it changes color at a very soft rate and with blurry effect.

I just wanted that type of background for my app.
What should I have to do for that

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Using following code might be good start for you:

```
public class BackgroundPainter {

  private static final int MIN = 800;
  private static final int MAX = 1500;

  private final Random random;

  public BackgroundPainter() {
    random = new Random();
  }

  public void animate(@NonNull final View target, @ColorInt final int color1,
      @ColorInt final int color2) {

    final ValueAnimator valueAnimator = ValueAnimator.ofObject(new ArgbEvaluator(), color1, color2);

    valueAnimator.setDuration(randInt(MIN, MAX));

    valueAnimator.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
      @Override public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animation) {
        target.setBackgroundColor((int) animation.getAnimatedValue());
      }
    });
    valueAnimator.addListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
      @Override public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
        //reverse animation
        animate(target, color2, color1);
      }
    });

    valueAnimator.setInterpolator(new AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator());
    valueAnimator.start();
  }

  private int randInt(int min, int max) {
    return random.nextInt((max - min) + 1) + min;
  }
}
```

With usage:

```
final View targetView = findViewById(R.id.root_view);

BackgroundPainter backgroundPainter = new BackgroundPainter();

int color1 = ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.colorAccent);
int color2 = ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.colorPrimary);

backgroundPainter.animate(targetView, color1, color2);
```

---

**Update**

For changing background which consists of more than one color, generally speaking of drawables instead of `ValueAnimator` you can try using below solution.

I have tested this code on Device with API 19 and 23.

Define colors in your `colors.xml`:

```
  <color name="color1">#9C27B0</color>
  <color name="color2">#FF4081</color>
  <color name="color3">#7B1FA2</color>
  <color name="color4">#F8BBD0</color>
  <color name="color5">#FF5252</color>
  <color name="color6">#607D8B</color>
  <color name="color7">#FF5722</color>
  <color name="color8">#FFA000</color>
```

Define gradients in `drawable`:

`gradient_1.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <gradient
      android:angle="45"
      android:endColor="@color/color2"
      android:startColor="@color/color1"
      android:type="linear"/>
</shape>
```

`gradient_2.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <gradient
      android:angle="-45"
      android:endColor="@color/color5"
      android:startColor="@color/color3"
      android:type="linear"/>
</shape>
```

`gradient_3.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <gradient
      android:angle="45"
      android:endColor="@color/color8"
      android:startColor="@color/color7"
      android:type="linear"/>
</shape>
```

Create class `GradientBackgroundPainter` in your project:

```
public class GradientBackgroundPainter {

  private static final int MIN = 4000;
  private static final int MAX = 5000;

  private final Random random;
  private final Handler handler;
  private final View target;
  private final int[] drawables;
  private final Context context;

  public GradientBackgroundPainter(@NonNull View target, int[] drawables) {
    this.target = target;
    this.drawables = drawables;
    random = new Random();
    handler = new Handler();
    context = target.getContext().getApplicationContext();
  }

  private void animate(final int firstDrawable, int secondDrawable, final int duration) {
    if (secondDrawable >= drawables.length) {
      secondDrawable = 0;
    }
    final Drawable first = ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, drawables[firstDrawable]);
    final Drawable second = ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, drawables[secondDrawable]);

    final TransitionDrawable transitionDrawable =
        new TransitionDrawable(new Drawable[] { first, second });

    target.setBackgroundDrawable(transitionDrawable);

    transitionDrawable.setCrossFadeEnabled(false);

    transitionDrawable.startTransition(duration);

    final int localSecondDrawable = secondDrawable;
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
      @Override public void run() {
        animate(localSecondDrawable, localSecondDrawable + 1, randInt(MIN, MAX));
      }
    }, duration);
  }

  public void start() {
    final int duration = randInt(MIN, MAX);
    animate(0, 1, duration);
  }

  public void stop() {
    handler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null);
  }

  private int randInt(int min, int max) {
    return random.nextInt((max - min) + 1) + min;
  }
}
```

And usage:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

  private GradientBackgroundPainter gradientBackgroundPainter;

  @Override protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    View backgroundImage = findViewById(R.id.root_view);

    final int[] drawables = new int[3];
    drawables[0] = R.drawable.gradient_1;
    drawables[1] = R.drawable.gradient_2;
    drawables[2] = R.drawable.gradient_3;

    gradientBackgroundPainter = new GradientBackgroundPainter(backgroundImage, drawables);
    gradientBackgroundPainter.start();
  }

  @Override protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    gradientBackgroundPainter.stop();
  }
}
```

Comment: Yeah it is working quite similarly. But it is for animation between two colors. I need to animate between 10-15 colors. Though it is smooth but only 1 color is appearing at one time. In my example of Instagram if you have noticed there are 2-3 color shades at one time on screen. This answer is helpful but if it solves these issues it would be amazing.

Comment: @Swarnveer I have updated my response with solution for gradient animation between more than one item

Comment: Thanks buddy, exactly what I wanted.
I could create more gradients and mention those in onCreate() to get more color combinations, can't I ? .

Comment: Yes, sure you can add more gradients

Comment: Woow... Thank you My Hero.. Really You are awesome.. Working Perfectly ..

Comment: Amazing. Thank you so much.

Comment: It is a good solution and it works. However, background is changing suddenly on Samsung Galaxy S3 Android 4.3. It is not smooth.

Comment: @jakubbialkowski can I use this in my commercial app? It's a really awesome effect. Thank you for your code.

Comment: @Alin Don't be shy and use it!

Comment: Hi... btw, what is `R.id.root_view` ?

Answer (score 0):

You can check the [Property Animation Api](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/prop-animation.html)

```
    int colorFrom = getResources().getColor(R.color.red);
int colorTo = getResources().getColor(R.color.blue);
ValueAnimator colorAnimation = ValueAnimator.ofObject(new ArgbEvaluator(), colorFrom, colorTo);
colorAnimation.setDuration(250); // milliseconds
colorAnimation.addUpdateListener(new AnimatorUpdateListener() {

    @Override
    public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animator) {
        textView.setBackgroundColor((int) animator.getAnimatedValue());
    }

});
colorAnimation.start();
```

Comment: you can use Color.parseColor("#ff0000") inside the getColor()

Comment: I added values of red and blue in colors.xml file. Now only blue color is showing in background. It's not dynamically changing.

Comment: increase the duration!!

Answer (score 0):

Use a `Relative layout`,
give an `id` to your `Relative layout`,downcast it ,and put into condition:

```
if(something){
    rlayout.setBackground(getResource().getDrawable().R.drawable.img);
} 
or    
use switch
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a TransitionDrawable to change between two drawables that you use for the background.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<transition xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<!-- use whatever drawables you want, gradients, shapes etc-->
<item android:drawable="@drawable/start" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/end" />
```

Transition Drawables in Android

```
TransitionDrawable trans = (TransitionDrawable) myLayout.getBackground();
trans.startTransition(2000);
```

I think this little code might help you.