# Changing gradient background like in Instagram Log In

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, gradient

How to make changing gradient background like in Instagram Log In?

In Android you do it like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36727608/3847113):

Is there a similar way to do it in Swift?

Answer (score 4):

If you want to change continuously change view's background color with animation you can set it something like this.

```
var colors: [UIColor] = [.red, .blue, .green]

func startAnimation(index: Int) {
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 2.5, delay: 0, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.curveEaseInOut, animations: {
        self.view.backgroundColor = self.colors[index]
        }) { (finished) in
            var currentIndex = index + 1
            if currentIndex == self.colors.count { currentIndex = 0 }
            self.startAnimation(index: currentIndex)
    }
}
```

And call this function with index `0`.

```
self.startAnimation(index: 0)
```

Answer (score 3):

In Swift3

Use CAGradientLayer with Using CABasicAnimation

I create PastelView Library to make alike instgram background animation effect

[image]

repo https://github.com/cruisediary/Pastel

Colors

```
var colors: [UIColor] = [UIColor(red: 156/255, green: 39/255, blue: 176/255, alpha: 1.0),
                         UIColor(red: 255/255, green: 64/255, blue: 129/255, alpha: 1.0),
                         UIColor(red: 123/255, green: 31/255, blue: 162/255, alpha: 1.0),
                         UIColor(red: 32/255, green: 76/255, blue: 255/255, alpha: 1.0),
                         UIColor(red: 32/255, green: 158/255, blue: 255/255, alpha: 1.0),
                         UIColor(red: 90/255, green: 120/255, blue: 127/255, alpha: 1.0),
                         UIColor(red: 58/255, green: 255/255, blue: 217/255, alpha: 1.0)]
```

Set Gradient

```
let gradient = CAGradientLayer()
gradient.frame = bounds
gradient.colors = currentGradientSet()
gradient.startPoint = CGPoint(x:0, y:1)
gradient.endPoint = CGPoint(x:1, y:0)
gradient.drawsAsynchronously = true
layer.insertSublayer(gradient, at: 0)
```

Add Animation to gradient

```
let animation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: Animation.keyPath)
animation.duration = animationDuration
animation.toValue = currentGradientSet()
animation.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards
animation.isRemovedOnCompletion = false
animation.delegate = self //this is important 
gradient.add(animation, forKey: Animation.key)
```

After end animation loop another color set looping

```
extension PastelView: CAAnimationDelegate {
    func animationDidStop(_ anim: CAAnimation, finished flag: Bool) {
        if flag {
            gradient.colors = currentGradientSet()
            animateGradient()
        }
    }
}
```

`Pastel` should help you :)

Answer (score 2):

You can do it pretty easily using `CAGradientLayer`:

```
let grad = CAGradientLayer()
grad.colors = [
    UIColor.red.cgColor, // top color
    UIColor.blue.cgColor // bottom color
]
grad.locations = [
    0.0, // start gradating at top of view
    1.0  // end gradating at bottom of view
] 

grad.frame = view.bounds
view.layer.addSublayer(grad)
```

You could increase the first item in locations (0.0) to start the gradating further down, or you could decrease 1.0 to complete gradation higher up. It's a bit tough to explain, drop this into a playground and mess around a bit until you get your desired effect.

Example gradient and playground from the code above:
[image]

Comment: Thanks! But is there a way that gradient changes slowly all the time, for example slowly from red to blue, then slowly from blue to green...?

Comment: I believe you're looking for something like this, check out the .gradient extension they've put on CAGradientLayer: https://github.com/hyperoslo/Hue

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this in **SWIFT 3**. You can give more colors in it.

```
let gradient1 = CAGradientLayer()
gradient1.frame = CGRect(origin: CGPoint.zero , size: CGSize (width: self.view.frame.size.width,height: self.view.frame.size.height))
gradient1.colors = [UIColor.red.cgColor, UIColor.blue.cgColor]
print(gradient1.frame)
view_gradient.layer.masksToBounds = true
view_gradient.layer.addSublayer(gradient1)
```

Hope this works for you.