# create spectrum using kivy texture

Tags: python, kivy

According to Kivy docs, this piece of code can be used to create a gradient from black and white. How does one create a spectrum using kivy textures?
I've been trying manipulating the samples variables but all I got is a gradient between only two color.

```
texture = Texture.create(size=(64, 64))

# create 64x64 rgb tab, and fill with values from 0 to 255
# we'll have a gradient from black to white
size = 64 * 64 * 3
buf = [int(x * 255 / size) for x in range(size)]
buf = b''.join(map(chr, buf))
texture.blit_buffer(buf, colorfmt='rgb', bufferfmt='ubyte')
with self.canvas:
    Rectangle(texture=texture, pos=self.pos, size=(64, 64))
```

[image: Something like this]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make a nested loop for that.
If you loop trough the pixels, and set the color.
The easiest thing would be to use hsv, and then convert to rgb.
So the outer loop sets the v (value), since that will be each row changing.
Inner loop will be the h (hue), each pixel in the row.
You can do something like this.

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.graphics.texture import Texture
from kivy.graphics import Rectangle
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from colorsys import hsv_to_rgb


class MyLayout(BoxLayout):

    def __init__(self,**kwargs):
        super(MyLayout,self).__init__(**kwargs)
        w = 64
        h = 64
        texture = Texture.create(size=(w, h))
        buf = []

        for i in range(h):
            for j in range(w):
                color = hsv_to_rgb(j/float(w),1,i/float(h)) # colorsys takes (0,0,0) to (1,1,1)
                pixel = [int(a*b) for a,b in zip(color,[255,255,255])] # since color goes from (0,0,0) to (1,1,1), we multiply by 255
                buf.extend(pixel)   

        buf = b''.join(map(chr, buf))
        texture.blit_buffer(buf, colorfmt='rgb', bufferfmt='ubyte')
        with self.canvas:
            Rectangle(texture=texture, pos=self.pos, size=(w, h))


class MyApp(App):

    def build(self):
        return MyLayout()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    MyApp().run()
```

Comment: nice job thanks, Im trying to make an animation that changes like instagram app login screen.

Comment: Thanks You are wellcome :) I have not seen the instagram login, but I guess its something with a spectrum changing then.

Comment: yeah, should I use Animation or should I define a schedule to do so? or should I use pyjenius to write java?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36726598/how-background-changes-at-login-in-instagram-app

Comment: @AminEtesamian if you use schedule and change the list each frame, python for loops might be too inefficient. I dont know what would be best in this case. numpy is fast tho

Comment: @AminEtesamian  now that I have looked on youtube at the instagram login screen, it seems like you could have this large canvas that would be much larger then your display, and then move the canvas. No array changing

Answer (score 1):

With some inspiration from [this](https://gist.github.com/tshirtman/3582544), I ended up with this code and this result.

```
from itertools import chain

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.graphics import Rectangle
from kivy.graphics.texture import Texture


class MyWidget(Widget):
    def __init__(self, **args):
        super(MyWidget, self).__init__(**args)

        self.texture = Texture.create(size=(5, 1), colorfmt="rgb")
        pixels = bytes([int(v * 255) for v in chain((0, 0, 0, 1), (0, 0, 0, 1))])
        buf = ''.join(pixels)
        self.texture.blit_buffer(buf, colorfmt='rgb', bufferfmt='ubyte')
        with self.canvas:
            Rectangle(pos=self.pos, size=self.size, texture=self.texture)


class TestApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return MyWidget(size=(368, 512))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    TestApp().run()
```

The trick is to try to display a texture bigger than its size.
[image: result]

Comment: I had to pass the `pixels` directly to `blit_buffer` - see also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67542947/1048572). Also, this simple `MyWidget` only draws the rectangle at the initial (static) `pos` and `size` so it doesn't work in a layout.